# how to pass jquery .val() from one page to php other page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page called index.php,where in menu i have to select city based on city  i have to show area names in auto suggetions.here i'm storing dropdown city list id in a as follows:
    now my theme is i have to pass jquery value to autocomplete.php page

**index.php:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="city" id="city">
           <option value=''>Select city</option>
           <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

                <option value="value="<?php echo $row['CITY_ID']; ?>"><?echo $row['CITY_TITLE']?></option>
                <?php } ?>
                </select>

searchget.js(included in index.php):

$("#city").change(function() {

var city_id=$('#city').val();
alert(city_id);


$.ajax({
         url: "autocompleteloc.php",
         type: "POST",

         data: { city_id1: city_id},
         success: function (result) {
                alert('success');
                CallSearch();

         }
     });

});
```

**autocomplete.php:**

this page have areas code :now that city id which is in jquery variable i have to pass in this page,

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
include("config.php");
    $q=$_POST['search'];
    $cid=$_REQUEST['city1'];
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
 echo $sql="SELECT DISTINCT UNIT_AREA,CITY_ID FROM UNIT WHERE UNIT_AREA LIKE '%$my_data%' and CITY_ID='$cid'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 if($result)
 {
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo $row['UNIT_AREA']."\n";
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have value in `php` which you pass in `ajax` param

`data: { CITY_ID1: CITY_ID},`

So, in `php` you can get value as

`$_POST['CITY_ID1']`

You should learn ajax post with PHP.

Comment: city id is not passing to autocomplete.php

Comment: try `print_r($_REQUEST)` in autocomplete.php

Comment: Please open this link and select bangalore city and type in search jayanagar

http://imcrinox.com/fadt/abc.php

Comment: `$_POST['q']` will get the value

Comment: sorry it's not coming i changed code to like this in autocomplete.php
  $q=$_POST['search'];
  $a=$_POST['city1'];
  // $a=$_REQUEST['city1'];
  //print_r($_REQUEST);
 //$a = isset($_POST['city1'])?$_POST['city1']:'city1 id is empty';
 $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
 echo $sql="SELECT DISTINCT UNIT_AREA,CITY_ID FROM UNIT WHERE UNIT_AREA LIKE '%$my_data%' and CITY_ID='$a'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: i did $_POST['q'] also but not passing

Comment: Thanks for u r help...it is not coming..if u want i will give you link once agin.other wise if you r free i will give my team viewer details..can u connect...if you don't mine

Comment: make sure you are suing correct php file, you mentioned `url: "autocompleteloc.php"` and check in console too, it's passing your textbox value in variable `q`